# Handling "error 500" in Spring MVC using @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, error-handling

(Firstly, I must say that I have been looking for answers on stackoverflow and the internet but haven't found sufficient answers)**I have just started my adventure with Spring MVC and my first task is to handle Internal Server Error using @ExceptionHandler annotation (first of all, i got to point out that I don't want to use error-page in web.xml). Briefly, whenever "error 500" occurs, there ought to be displayed a proper site with a link to the home site. So, my problem is that I don't know how to make method which follows `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` invoked each time error 500 takes place.

Answer (score 2):

If you use java configuration you may try like follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ExcpConfig {

    @Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver= new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings); // None by default
        resolver.setExceptionAttribute("ErrorOccurred"); // Default is "exception"
        resolver.setDefaultErrorView("500"); // 500.jsp
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still seeing a JBoss error page with a stack trace if an error occurs rendering a jsp. There has to be an easy way to capture these kinds of errors so they aren't exposed to the end users.

Comment: @Roger If you create a page like 500.jsp then It will render your custom 500.jsp page rather than jboss error page.

Comment: I have a "500.jsp" in the same view directory which my 400.jsp, 403.jsp, ect. all reside. Those are handled through an `@ControllerAdvice` class which is of course not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually do what you want with the @ExceptionHandler annotation. This is only for exceptions in a specific controller, not for more general things like error 500's.

You probably want to look at implementing the HandlerExceptionResolver interface, and wiring that in for more general exceptions.

Here's a link to it in the spring docs.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Let me know if you need any other help.